# Equalize number of columns in csv data

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I'm parsing some contact data from a PDF-file converted to csv which has resulted in a different column count per row based on missing entries.

Is there a way to correct this using sed, awk, cut etc by making sure some columns that are easy to pattern match up - fx making sure the email-addresses are in the same columns when available and others like "Lifetime member" or "Guest" when email is not available?

The first column is a person/company's name but the rest is arbitrary. The point is to extract contact information(like email, phone number etc) and put it in the same columns, when available.
My idea would be to check if the email is in the 6th column and if not then add a number of empty columns before it etc

**Example data:**

```
Steve Smith;9828;1;+1234 567 2345;Guest;steve@example.org;1;1 12th st;48572 Nowhere
Steve Jobs;+1234 567 2345;noreply@example.org;1;48572 Nowhere
John Smith;9828;1;+1234 567 2345;Lifetime member;1;1 23rd st;48572 Nowhere
Peter Blavounius;2312;peter@blavounius.com
```

**Wanted output:**

```
Steve Smith;9828;1;+1234 567 2345;Guest;steve@example.org;1;1 12th st;48572 Nowhere
Steve Jobs;+1234 567 2345;;;;noreply@example.org;1;;48572 Nowhere
John Smith;9828;1;+1234 567 2345;Lifetime member;1;1 23rd st;48572 Nowhere
Peter Blavounius;2312;;;;peter@blavounius.com
```

Comment: I think you'll have to come up with a telephone number pattern, a street pattern, a city pattern, etc. Then you'll have to test each field of each record to see if it matches one of those patterns. Good luck.

Comment: That does NOT look like output you'd want as it's jumbling the fields. For example, it has the phone number in field 4 of the first line but field 2 of the 2nd line. Do what @glennjackman suggests and you can create output that has every type of data item consistently in the same position on every line.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up my formatting Ed! I had some trouble getting it right. And thank you both for your suggestions - it's exactly what I need for my purposes, though it obviously needs some tweaking to be of general usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you started but it is not complete, you still need to identify other fields, all I've done so far is identify a couple of the fields to show you the approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=";"
    ARGV[ARGC] = ARGV[ARGC-1]
    ARGC++
}

{
    name = tel = email = digs4 = ""
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            name=$i; $i=""; nameFld = 1
        }
        else if ($i ~ /^\+/) {
            tel=$i; $i=""; telFld = (i > telFld ? i : telFld)
        }
        else if ($i ~ /@/) {
            email=$i; $i=""; emailFld = (i > emailFld ? i : emailFld)
        }
        else if ($i ~ /^[0-9]{4}$/) {
            digs4=$i; $i=""; digs4Fld = (i > digs4Fld ? i : digs4Fld)
        }
    }
    maxFlds = (NF > maxFlds ? NF : maxFlds)
}

NR>FNR {
    for (i=1;i<=maxFlds;i++) {
        if (i == nameFld)       { $i = name }
        else if (i == telFld)   { $i = tel }
        else if (i == emailFld) { $i = email }
        else if (i == digs4Fld) { $i = digs4 }
        else { $i = $i } # make sure null fields are present
    }
    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Steve Smith;9828;1;+1234 567 2345;Guest;steve@example.org;1;1 12th st;48572 Nowhere
Steve Jobs;;;+1234 567 2345;48572 Nowhere;noreply@example.org;;;
John Smith;9828;1;+1234 567 2345;Lifetime member;;1 23rd st;48572 Nowhere;
Peter Blavounius;2312;;;;peter@blavounius.com;;;
```

It does 2 passes on your input file - the first to identify that largest field number that matches each regexp as that's where you want every field matching that regexp to appear in the output, and the second to identify the fields, clear out their location in the record, and then place every field in the right location.

You could identify what a field means by matching it's context to a regexp like above or by its fixed position in the line (e.g. the persons name is always in field 1) or by it's relative position to something else (e.g. a single digit occurring before vs after the email address or before/after the 3rd field number or....)

Hope it makes sense. Add some printfs and play with it a bit and ask questions if you're confused after that.

Comment: Having a way to regex for each pattern was exactly what I needed! Thank you so very much! + seems to need an escape though. `if ($i ~ /^\+/) {`

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to need an escape since any of the "repetition" RE metacharacters simply have their literal meaning at the start of an RE since you can't have repetitions of nothing and in this case you can't have "one or more occurrences" (`+`) of the start of a string (`^`). Did you get an error message or unexpected behavior from not having it escaped?

Comment: Seems logical. But sadly not the case here. Apparently it's a syntax error: `awk: tst.awk: line 13: regular expression compile failed (syntax error ^* or ^+)
^+`

Comment: Yup you're right. gawk handles it fine until you add `--posix` and then it produces an error message. I'll update my answer, thanks for pointing that out.